# Gradle custom configuration dependency on subproject does not resolve

Tags: gradle, kotlin, java-9

I have a custom configuration:

```
configurations {
    unnamedJavaModule {
        canBeResolved true
    }
}
```

**Gradle version: 5.6**

This configuration is used to add a dependency to a subproject like so:

```
unnamedJavaModule (project(':unnamed.module'))
```

The problem is at compilation, the kotlin compiler complains that some package defined inside the module does not exist.

I tried to fix it by adding the configuration the `compileKotlin` classpath, but that didn't work.

```
compileKotlin {
    doFirst {
        classpath += configurations.unnamedJavaModule
    }
}
```

> Unresolved reference: packagename

Where `packagename` is the name of the package it is not finding. This is annoying because the package exists in the subproject. It is not complaining that the package is in an unnamed module, it is just not finding it. Changing the dependency to use `implementation` configuration, seems to fix this, but I don't want to use the existing `implementation` configuration

```
implementation (project(':unnamed.module')) // This works
```

How do I fix this so that the custom configuration is resolved properly?